# Model inherited from AbstractUser doesn't hash password field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

I have a model that is inherited of AbstractUser, something like this :

```
class Driver(AbstractUser):
  dni = models.CharField(max_length=8,validators=[validate_dni],unique=True)
  license = models.CharField(max_length=9,unique=True)
  birthday = models.DateField()
  sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX_CHOICES)
  creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now = True)
```

According to this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/

> If you’re entirely happy with Django’s User model and you just want to
>   add some additional profile information, you can simply subclass
>   django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser and add your custom profile
>   fields. This class provides the full implementation of the default
>   User as an abstract model.

But, in my admin view, the field of password is a simple text input and the password is saved as raw text. I could try with AbstractBaseUser but first I need to clarify this issue. I'm starting with Django, so I'm a little newbie.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define a function to hash that password. I think you directly save it to database.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ............
    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(MyForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I thought that it isn't necessary to edit the save method or call to "set_password" method explicitly.

Answer (score 21):

You don't have to actually define your own function. You just need to use register it with the `UserAdmin` class from `django.contrib.auth.admin` and it works out of the box.

Explicitly, in your admin.py file make sure you have the following:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
admin.site.register(CustomUserModel, UserAdmin)
```

If you have additional custom fields on your model, the above way of registering will make them not shown in the admin. In this case, you can make it work by making your custom Admin class inherit from the `UserAdmin` class, like the following:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

@admin.register(CustomUserModel)
class CustomUserModelAdmin(UserAdmin):
    ...
```

Comment: When I register it with `UserAdmin` my custom options disappear. Any idea why is that?

Comment: Yeah, the admin classes specify what fields and such appear. You can make a new class that inherits from `UserAdmin` and includes your custom fields. Then register that new admin class with your custom user model.

Comment: my custom fields disappear from the admin after adding this line admin.site.register(CustomUserModel, UserAdmin)

Comment: I have the same thing

Comment: @mr_bulrathi: I updated the answer to include an example with a custom admin model which is what you'll need to do to get both the password hashing correct as well as have your custom fields shown.

Comment: Should `@admin.register(CustomUserModel)` read `@admin.register(CustomUserModelAdmin)`?

Answer (score -1):

Procedure  djnago >=3.0

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = [('1', '1 class'),('2', '2 class'),('3', '3 class'),('4', '4 class'),('5', '5 class'),('6', '6 class'),('7', '7 class'),('8', '8 class'),('9', '9 class'),('10', '10th class'),]
    
    class User(AbstractUser):
        type = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=(('1','Student'), ('2','Professor'), ('3','lower_staf')), default='1')  
    
    
    class Student(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True )
        gender = models.BooleanField(choices=((1,'Male'), (2,'Female'), (3,'Trans')), 
    
        def __str__(self):
            return '{}'.format(self.user)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from.models import User, Student
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + ((None, {'fields': ('type',)}),)
    add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.add_fieldsets + ((None, {'fields': ('type',)}),)

class Student_admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Student, Student_admin)
```